# List my google groups for NON ADMIN with python

Tags: python, google-groups, google-groups-api

I am trying to list/update my google groups programatically using Python. Using the console, they are there : https://groups.google.com/my-groups?pli=1

I have followed : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python?hl=fr with basically the following code :

```
  service = build("admin", "directory_v1", credentials=creds)

  # Call the Admin SDK Directory API
  print("Getting the first 10 users in the domain")
  results = (
      service.users()
      .list(customer="my_customer", maxResults=10, orderBy="email")
      .execute()
  )
  users = results.get("users", [])
```

However it does not work since I am not an admin on the workspace ('Not Authorized to access this resource/api'). Can you list your groups without being an admin ( I can do it using the console ! )